# solve a system of 4 equations with erf

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to solve a system of 4 equations with erf function. I have tried with nonlinsolve but I don't get an exact solution for each of my 4 unknowns.

Here is what I have tried:

```
import sympy as sp
import math
from scipy import special #library to use erf
from sympy import Symbol, Eq, symbols, nonlinsolve, sqrt

sqrt2=math.sqrt(2)

CAL_RR=[
    (10,66),
    (14,33),
    (20,33),
    (35,66)    
]


m1, s1, m2, s2 = symbols('m1, s1, m2, s2', real=True)

eq0 = Eq(1+(sp.erf((-CAL_RR[0][0]-m1)/(sqrt2*s1))+sp.erf((CAL_RR[1][0]-m2)/(sqrt2*s2)))/2*100,CAL_RR[0][1])
eq1 = Eq(1+(sp.erf((-CAL_RR[1][0]-m1)/(sqrt2*s1))+sp.erf((CAL_RR[1][0]-m2)/(sqrt2*s2)))/2*100,CAL_RR[1][1])
eq2 = Eq(1+(sp.erf((-CAL_RR[2][0]-m1)/(sqrt2*s1))+sp.erf((CAL_RR[2][0]-m2)/(sqrt2*s2)))/2*100,CAL_RR[2][1])
eq3 = Eq(1+(sp.erf((-CAL_RR[3][0]-m1)/(sqrt2*s1))+sp.erf((CAL_RR[3][0]-m2)/(sqrt2*s2)))/2*100,CAL_RR[3][1])


res=nonlinsolve([eq0,eq1,eq2,eq3],[m1,s1,m2,s2])
print(res)
```

I get:

```
FiniteSet((15.0*(-2.33333333333333*erfinv(-erf((0.707106781186547*m2 - 24.7487373415292)/s2) - 13/10) + 2.33333333333333*erfinv(-erf((0.707106781186547*m2 - 14.1421356237309)/s2) - 16/25) + erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 24.7487373415292/s2) - 13/10))/(erfinv(-erf((0.707106781186547*m2 - 24.7487373415292)/s2) - 13/10) - erfinv(-erf((0.707106781186547*m2 - 14.1421356237309)/s2) - 16/25)), Complement({10.6066017177982/(erfinv(-erf((0.707106781186547*m2 - 24.7487373415292)/s2) - 13/10) - erfinv(-erf((0.707106781186547*m2 - 14.1421356237309)/s2) - 16/25))}, {0}), m2, Complement({s2}, {0})), (1.4142135623731*(-1.33333333333333*erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 24.7487373415292/s2) - 13/10) + 2.33333333333333*erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 14.1421356237309/s2) - 16/25))/(0.0942809041582063*erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 24.7487373415292/s2) - 13/10) - 0.0942809041582063*erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 14.1421356237309/s2) - 16/25)), Complement({1/(0.0942809041582063*erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 24.7487373415292/s2) - 13/10) - 0.0942809041582063*erfinv(-erf(0.707106781186547*m2/s2 - 14.1421356237309/s2) - 16/25))}, {0}), m2, Complement({s2}, {0})))
```

When I simplify the problem to 2 equations, I have no problem but my result would be more accurate like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SymPy root instead of math.sqrt:

```
sqrt2=sp.sqrt(2)
```

That keeps the exact value for Sympy to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I think it doesn't answer my problem. Also if I replace as you suggest I get this error `ufunc 'erf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Hmm, I ran your exact code without errors in both cases. So there is a difference in configuration that causes your error. Maybe scipy version?
Python 3.8
SciPy 1.8.1

Comment: Thanks for commenting @StephenT ! I don't get an error neither but a solution like the one at the end of my initial post. My problem with that solution is that I don't get directly a real value for each unknown. 4 equations for 4 unknowns, from a mathematical point of view it should work but maybe it is not possible because of the erf solution